# Как сохранить состояние списка при повороте экрана?

Tags: java, android

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что приложение не сохраняет состояние активити при смене ориентации экрана.

Погуглив эту инфу я добавил пару методов, как было сказано, но ничего не происходит. Прошу помощи в решении этой проблемы.

Вот код:

```
public class ReaderActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_reader);

        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMainText);

        try {
            openBook(getIntent().getStringExtra("PATH_TO_BOOK"));
        }
        catch (IOException exc){
            System.out.println("IO Error!");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы добавили методы для сохранения/восстановления состояния, но в них ничего не сохраняете/восстанавливаете. Состояние какого списка Вы хотите сохранить?

Comment: ListView. Мне нужно сохранить все элементы которые отображены в данный момент и потом их в таком же порядке вывести на экран. У меня есть идея сохранить нужные параметры и просто перерисовать потом список, но мне кажется есть менее ресурсоемкий метод.

Comment: Да нет, все делается именно так. В `Bundle` сохраняете список с отображаемыми данными и, опционально, состояние скролла. Далее из того же `Bundle` все это восстанавливаете.

Comment: Для ответа на Ваш вопрос не хватает структуры отображаемых в списке данных.

Comment: Предположим что массив с данными для отображения имеется.

Comment: Ну, что массив имеется, это, конечно, замечательно и понятно. Я имел ввиду какого рода данные в списке отображаются. Окей, сейчас самый простой случай объясню.

Comment: Список из TextView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не возитесь с onStateInstanceState/onRestoreInstanceState. Лучше сразу возьмите фрейморк, который из коробки поддерживает view state, и забудьте об этой проблеме навсегда.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

https://github.com/Arello-Mobile/Moxy

Смотреть здесь: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KZ0j2K9VAf8

Читать здесь: https://habrahabr.ru/post/276189/

Answer (score 3):

Далее будет представлен *базовый* способ сохранения состояния объектов, который предоставляется *из коробки*. Также можно использовать другие средства для решения подобных задач, но только после того, как будут изучены подобные *фундаментальные* вещи.

---

Предположим, нужно сохранить состояние `ArrayList<String> mStrings` в процессе жизненного цикла активити.

В самом простом случае для этого можно использовать метод `onSaveInstanceState(...)` и, опционально, метод `onRestoreInstanceState(...)`.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final String LIST_KEY = "LIST_KEY";

    private ArrayList<String> mStrings;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            mStrings = new ArrayList<>();
            mStrings.add("First line");
            mStrings.add("Second line");
            mStrings.add("Third line");
        } else {
            mStrings = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList(LIST_KEY);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putStringArrayList(LIST_KEY, mStrings);
    }
}
```

При запуске приложения создается `ArrayList<String> mStrings` и заполняется тремя строками.

При повороте экрана в частности и при изменении конфигурации устройства в целом, перед вызовом метода `onStop()` будет вызван метод `onSaveInstanceState(...)` в котором можно сохранить данные в объект типа `Bundle`.

Далее эти сохраненные данные можно восстановить в методах: `onCreate(...)` и `onRestoreInstanceState(...)`.

Таким образом, здесь в методе `onSaveInstanceState(...)` мы помещаем список в объект `outState`, а далее, в методе `onCreate(...)` восстанавливаем наш список.